# RHEL6 can't connect to local oracle db

Tags: oracle, redhat

I downloaded Oracle database `oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm`. After installation, I set default password to `password`.

Then I download and installed `instantclient-basic` `instantclient-sqlplus`.
My `~/.bash_profile` paths:

```
ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64
PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib
export ORACLE_HOME
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export PATH
```

Then I tried to login from sqlplus as: `sqlplus system`, and enter password `password`. It gave me error `ORA-12162: TNS:net service name is incorrectly specified`.

I checked online and seems like if I do those steps, it should be working.

Similar issue link: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/281843

Comment: start listener using lsnrctl <service-name> start

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your `ORACLE_SID` environment variable, to match the database you installed/created. [This is mentioned in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25054_01/server.1111/e10897/em_manage.htm#CACHIJDC). Without that set:

```
$ echo $ORACLE_SID

$ sqlplus -s -l x/y
ERROR:
ORA-12162: TNS:net service name is incorrectly specified


SP2-0751: Unable to connect to Oracle.  Exiting SQL*Plus
```

After setting it:

```
$ export ORACLE_SID=XE
$ ./sqlplus -s -l x/y
ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; login denied


SP2-0751: Unable to connect to Oracle.  Exiting SQL*Plus
```

Where the ORA-01017 is because I've used fake credentials, but you can see it's talking to the database to validate those now.

You can set `ORACLE_SID` in your `.bash_profile` along with the other environment variables.

You can also connect over SQL*Net, without setting `$ORACLE_SID` or to override it. If your listener is running (`lsnrctl status` to check) you can use an alias defined in your `tnsnames.ora` file, which would typically match the SID:

```
$ sqlplus x/y@XE
```

Or without the file you can use the [easy connect](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e41945/naming.htm#NETAG255) syntax:

```
$ sqlplus x/y@//localhost:1521/XE
```

which takes the hostname/IP address and port that the listener is actually listening on (which again you can get from `lsnrctl status`) and the service name of the database instance - which is also typically the same as or similar to the SID, and I think is going to be XE in your case.

You can [read more in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25054_01/server.1111/e10897/network.htm#CIHJHJGJ).

Incidentally, you seem to be picking up the full client based on your `$PATH` setting, rather than the instant client, so you may not have needed to download that separately.

Comment: Thanks. I know this question seems stupid. Is my installation method correct? My coworker used this method to install in centos. But some other articles used disk to install or a package from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index-092322.html

Comment: If you've followed the XE installation documentation then it should be OK - you haven't said you've done anything odd. Installing the instant client as well may just have been a bit redundant. But you can use either client (or others, like SQL Developer) to access your DB if it was created properly and you have the listener configured and running.